# make a schedule from Google Spreadsheet to Google Calendar using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please give me feedback.
I would like to add a schedule from Google Spreadsheets to Google Calendar automatically.

Here is the script I wrote and when it runs, the values that I want to show appears well.
[image]
However, it still does not make a new schedule for Google Calendar.

```js
function goCreate() {
  const calID = ""
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startDay = console.info( ss.getRange("D13").getValue());
  var endDay = console.info( ss.getRange("G13").getValue());
  var guests = console.info( ss.getRange("C8").getValue());
  var location = console.info( ss.getRange("D14").getValue());
  var description = console.info( ss.getRange("D16").getValue());
  var details = {'description': description, 'location' : location};
  
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test",new Date(startDay),details);
}

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Sync to Cal").addItem('Create Events Now', 'goCreate').addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, it seems that the value of `console.info` is directly used as the variable for `createAllDayEvent`. But, `console.info` returns no value. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. If your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function goCreate() {
  const calID = "";
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startDay = ss.getRange("D13").getValue();
  var endDay = ss.getRange("G13").getValue();
  var guests = ss.getRange("C8").getValue();
  var location = ss.getRange("D14").getValue();
  var description = ss.getRange("D16").getValue();

  // console.log({ startDay, endDay, guests, location, description }); // If you want to see the values in the log, please use this line.

  var details = {'description': description, 'location' : location}; // or { 'description': description, 'location': location, 'guests': guests };
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent("Test", new Date(startDay), details);
}
```

- When this script is run, a new all-day event is created using the values of `startDay, location, description`.
- By the way, in your script, `endDay` and `guests` are not used. In the case of `createAllDayEvent` method, only one date is used. And, if you want to use `guests`, please include it in `details` like `var details = { 'description': description, 'location': location, 'guests': guests };`

#### References:

- [info() of Class console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#info())
- [createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createalldayeventtitle,-date,-options)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. 
if the guests are two, how can i make the code? even, 3?

Comment: @Lucas Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `if the guests are two, how can i make the code? even, 3?`, in this case, the value of `guests` is required to be a string value separated with a comma like `sample1@samplemail,sample2@samplemail,,,`. From your script, if you want to retrieve the value of guests from `C8`, please put the emails like `sample1@samplemail,sample2@samplemail,,,` into `C8`. And, please use `var details = { 'description': description, 'location': location, 'guests': guests };`.